# Continuous function on compact topological space

Tags: general-topology

I came across the following statement.

Let $X$ a uncountable set, $p \notin X$ and $X^* = X \cup \{p\}$. Let $$\mathcal O := \{O \subseteq X^* \mid O \subseteq X \text{ or } p \in O \text{ and } X \setminus O \text{ finite}\}.$$
Then $(X^*, \mathcal O)$ is a compact topological space.

This was pretty easy to show. Now to the statement I couldn't show:

If $f \in C(X^*, \mathbb C)$, then $f(x) = f(p)$ for all $x \in X^*$ except for countable many.

I tried to use that $f^{-1}(\mathbb C \setminus \{f(p)\}) \in \mathcal O$ but I couldn't manage to get a prove from that. Further I know that $f(X^*)$ is compact, so every cover $\mathcal U$ from $f(X^*)$ has a finite subcover say $U_1, \dots, U_n$ and there exists a $U_j$ with $f(p) \in U_j \iff p \in f^{-1}(U_j)$. But I really struggle to use that.

I would be thankful for some hints.

Comment: I don’t think the statement is true. As far as I can see, if you pick a countable sequence $\{x_n:n\in\mathbb N\}\subseteq X$, and put $f(x_n)=1/n$, and $f(y)=0$ otherwise, then $f\colon X^*\to\mathbb C$ is continuous, right? However, it is true that if $f$ is continuous, then $f(x)=f(p)$ for all but *countably* many $x\in X^*$.

Comment: Oh, I think that I maybe translated it wrong. I will fix it immediatly.

Comment: Would you maybe elaborate why it is? I can't see that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $B_{\frac{1}{n}}(f( p))$ the ball of radius $\frac{1}{n}$ around $f( p)$ in $\mathbb{C}$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$. For every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, since $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}(B_{\frac{1}{n}}(f( p)))$ is open in $\mathcal{O}$ and contains $p$, therefore its complement, say $C_n$, has finitely many elements. Moreover, $f^{-1}( f( p))=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} f^{-1}(B_{\frac{1}{n}}(f( p)))$. Since $X^{*}\setminus f^{-1}( f( p)) = \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}C_n$, it has at most countably many elements and we are done.